# No buffer space available : how to track

Tags: vps

when I receive a lot of traffic on my vps, I receive the error that there is no buffer space available. I would like to track if there is a leak, for example non-cached api requests, or to see from which process/scripts the requests are made. I know that the best solution is to move on own server when, but am still looking for a vps solution. Thanks!